# Organizing data in Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm puling some data from a webpage using selenium

```
table_body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').text
print(table_body)
```

this give me back

```
'1 LA, California 3 bed room 845,600 \n1
2 OK, Oklahoma city 3 bed room 160,000 \n2
3 TX, Dallas 1 bed room 60,000' \n3
```

however, it's all one string with multiple line.
Is there a way I can separate each individual character so I can append it to a dictionary. I've tried to `.append` it to a list and it returned `[[...]],[[...]]` and I tried to `.update` it a dictionary and I get an error saying `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required`

UPDATE: I think my question was confusing the way I formatted it.

Comment: could you please show a sample output?

Comment: @JkShaw there is the output. When I pull it, it gives me each TR with all the data then makes a new string so when I put it in a list at the end of each property it just creates a new line \n2, \n3, \n4, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming table_body is a string,

```
>>> table_body.split("|")
```

Edit: This should work then.

```
>>> for row in table_body.split("|"):
...    print row.split(',')
```

Edit 2: If there are no '|' symbols and only newlines.

```
>>> for row in table_body.split("\n"):
...    print row.split(',')
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work because it's all one big string

Comment: edited my answer based on your comment. try that and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

To get `dictionary` from string with default value `None`, for example:

```
>>> table_body = 'Rank | Name | State | Position | cost | value'

# List with stripped whitespaces
>>> [s.strip() for s in table_body.split('|')]
['Rank', 'Name', 'State', 'Position', 'cost', 'value']

# Dictionary from tab table_body
>>> dict([(s.strip(), None) for s in table_body.split('|')])
{'Name': None, 'value': None, 'State': None, 'cost': None, 'Rank': None, 'Position': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider var lst:

```
lst = 'Rank | Name | State | Position | cost | value | etc...'
```

If you make:

```
>>> table_body = lst.split("|")
```

Then print table_body:

```
>>>print (table_body)
['Rank ', ' Name ', ' State ', ' Position ', ' cost ', ' value ', ' 
  etc...']
```

If you try

```
>>> dict1 = dict(table_bodyt)
```

you will get an error:

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

### Why?

Because for to convert a list into a dict, each element of the list need be a sublist with two elements, one for key and other for value. For exemple:

```
>>> lst2 = [[n,table_body[n]] for n in range(len(table_body))]
>>> dict(lst2)
{0: 'Rank ',
 1: ' Name ',
 2: ' State ',
 3: ' Position ',
 4: ' cost ',
 5: ' value ',
 6: ' etc...'}
```

Comment: The solution is good, but you should be stripping out the leading and trailing spaces too.

Comment: @Sidon ['Rank ', ' Name ', ' State ', ' Position ', ' cost ', ' value ', ' 
  etc...'] all of this is one string then the next item with all the same the same properties is just moved to a new line. So all the items are grouped together inside one big string.

Comment: @David So you can create a list each line (a string)  and then a list of this lists, and finally, a dict, following my code above.